# how to draw shadow along with path on canvas like google graphs

Tags: android, android-canvas

I want to draw shadow along with path of graph, like google graphs as same as below image, on custom view's canvas but not sure how to do that.
[image]

Comment: I don't think it is a shadow, instead it looks like a gradient masked by the graph.

Answer (score 2):

I think I might have found a solution using [`android.graphics.Shader`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Shader) and [`android.graphics.LinearGradient`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/LinearGradient) as a background for the path

The result looks like something like this [image: GraphView example]

This is the file `GraphView` I've created

```
public class GraphView extends View {
    private float[] mValues = {};
    private Paint mPaint;
    private Paint mPaintGradient;
    private final int mColor = Color.GREEN; // You can then set this using AttributeSet
    private Path mPath;
    private Shader mGradientShader;

    public GraphView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(null, 0);
    }

    public GraphView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs, 0);
    }

    public GraphView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(attrs, defStyle);
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        final TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.GraphView, defStyle, 0);
        mPaint = new Paint(mColor);
        mPaintGradient = new Paint();
        mPath = new Path();

        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        mPaint.setColor(mColor);
        mPath.setFillType(Path.FillType.WINDING);

        a.recycle();
    }
    private void initShader(){
        //Set as you need
        int[] colors = { Color.parseColor("#3f00ff00"), Color.TRANSPARENT };
        float[] positions = { 0, 1f };

        //Get the max point of the graph to start the gradient from there
        float max = mValues[0];
        for(float value: mValues)
            max = Math.max(value, max);

        float startShaderY = toGraphPoint(max);

        mGradientShader = new LinearGradient(0, startShaderY, 0, getHeight(), colors, positions,  Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);


    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        //Draw Background
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        if(mPaintGradient.getShader() == null) {
            initShader();
            mPaintGradient.setShader(mGradientShader);
        }

        if(mValues.length >= 1){
            float graphValuePos = toGraphPoint(mValues[0]);
            mPath.moveTo(0, graphValuePos);
        }
        for(int i = 1; i<mValues.length; i++){
            float graphValuePos = toGraphPoint(mValues[i]); // here handle how the value should appear on the graph on the Y axis (useful if you want to change vertical scale or change between logarithmic and linear scale)
            mPath.lineTo(i*100, graphValuePos);
        }
        canvas.drawPath(mPath,mPaintGradient);
        //Here draw the horizontal lines
        canvas.drawPath(mPath,mPaint);
    }

    public void setGraphValues(float[] values){
        mValues = values;
        invalidate();
    }
    
    public float toGraphPoint(float value){
        // here handle how the value should appear on the graph on the Y axis (useful if you want to change vertical scale or change between logarithmic and linear scale)
        return getHeight() - value;
    }

}
```

and you can use it like this

```
GraphView graphView = findViewById(R.id.graph);
float values[] = { 50f,100f,400f,300f,10f,50f,20f };
graphView.setGraphValues(values);
```

**So how does it work?**

First we draw a background, then create the Path using the values and we draw it twice:

1. We draw the inside using `mGradientShader` which is used to draw the shader
2. We draw the stroke using `mPaint`

(Remember that you can draw the horizontal lines between theese two steps)

Hope this helps!

Comment: It didn't work, it drawn the line but shadow was not drawn along the path.
Thanks for the effort though.
how I tested it is, I added this file in my test project and added in to the fragment and passed suggested values but no luck.
Also I want shadow from the path line to bottom of graph.

Comment: @Sharad Can you share the values of the path you ve used so I can test and fix my code? Also for the shadow going to tge bottom it's necessary just tweak the float, I think I'll fix my code and start the gradient from the highest point from the values instead of the top of the canvas

Comment: @Sharad I fixed my code as said, check if it works

Comment: Hey @Mirco0, thanks for updating your code. I already got working solution as I posted below so no need to use another solution.
Thanks again for your efforts.

I downvoted earlier because it was not working as expected but as you said you have fixed it so I will upvote it again.

Comment: @Sharad Oh, thank you for clarifying. I haven't noticed youf answer, hoping I guided you towards the right direction

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
class ShadowLine @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
   
   private val path = Path()

    private val shadowColors = intArrayOf(
        ContextCompat.getColor(
            context,
            R.color.gray500
        ),
        ContextCompat.getColor(
            context,
            R.color.gray400
        ),
        ContextCompat.getColor(
            context,
            R.color.gray300
        ),
        ContextCompat.getColor(
            context,
            R.color.gray200
        ),
        Color.TRANSPARENT
    )

    private val linePaint = Paint().apply {
        isAntiAlias = true
        color = Color.BLACK
        style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        strokeWidth = 4f
        strokeCap = Paint.Cap.ROUND
    }

    private val shadowPaint = Paint().apply {
        isAntiAlias = true
        style = Paint.Style.FILL
        strokeWidth = 4f
        strokeCap = Paint.Cap.ROUND

        shader = LinearGradient(
            0f,
            0f,
            0f,
            resources.getDimension(R.dimen.shadow_line_height),
            shadowColors,
            null,
            Shader.TileMode.CLAMP
        )
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        drawLineWithPath(canvas)
    }

    private fun drawLineWithPath(canvas: Canvas) {
        path.moveTo(10f, 500f)

        path.lineTo(200f, 200f)
        path.lineTo(400f, 400f)
        path.lineTo(600f, 300f)
        path.lineTo(800f, 300f)
        path.lineTo(1000f, 600f)

        canvas.drawPath(path, shadowPaint)
        canvas.drawPath(path, linePaint)
    }
}
```

[image]